# How to extract the data table from a .CEL file on python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a .CEL file dowloaded from [www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser). Need to extract the numpy array of data from the file. I imported CelFile from Bio.Affy library:

```
with open('Myfile.CEL') as f:
    c = CelFile.read(f)
    print(c)
```

This does not show any data set! Any idea of how to use CelFile ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The read() method returns with a record object (it is the c in your example). This object has several arrays like intensities, stdevs, npix, etc, you need these.

Here you find some examples how to use it:

https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Affy.CelFile.Record-class.html

Sometimes the help() function can give you enough information how to use a class, function, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to see the raw data but those you mentioned show some statistics. I read the help, it only explains the statistics.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used the biopython, so I don't know what you exactly need. Look at the source, maybe that is more useful for you. https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Affy.CelFile-pysrc.html#Record

Comment: Here there is a tutorial, did you read it, before you started your project? http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

Comment: Here there is an example CEL file, please open it. Which data do you need to extract from this file? If you don't see them maybe you need to analyze other files, not the CEL files. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biopython/biopython/master/Tests/Affy/affy_v3_example.CEL

Comment: Thank you for the links. You're right, the raw data I was looking for was in a .txt file from the same source!